# How to prove P = NP if problem Π ϵ NP-complete and Problem complement Πc ϵ NP?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, np, polynomial-time, p-vs-np

How to prove if P = NP if problem Π ϵ  NP-complete and Problem complement Πc ϵ NP?
OR
P = NP if NPC intersects with Co-NPC

Comment: This is a repost of a question posed 3 hours earlier. https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/127453/prove-that-if-npc-%e2%88%a9-co-npc-%e2%89%a0-%cf%86-then-np-p

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that if NPC ∩ co-NPC ≠ φ then NP = P](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/127453/prove-that-if-npc-%e2%88%a9-co-npc-%e2%89%a0-%cf%86-then-np-p)

Comment: yes, it does, it helped me a lot, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proving $NP=co-NP$ doesn't necessarily mean that $P=NP$. Although, the other way around *is* correct:
Assume $P=NP$, then $co-NP=co-P=P=NP$.

Answer (score 0):

You won't find anything useful with our current knowledge. However, a change to $\Pi^c\in \mbox{P}$ will get you $\mbox{P}=\mbox{NP}$.

Comment: Maybe you could expand on this a bit? Won't find anything useful for what?